# Is there a function that allows you to generate the highest multiple of a number below a certain boundary?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Say for example, that I want the highest multiple of 36 below 100. Is there a function that allows me to generate this with two arbitrary numbers?

Comment: $36\left\lfloor \frac{100}{36}\right\rfloor$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ the number whose multiple you're trying to find and $y$ is the upper bound what you're looking for is
$$x{\left\lfloor{ y\over x}\right\rfloor}$$

where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).